# How to get and set json data on recyclerView?

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview

Android Question?

I get json value and set on recyclerView ,How can make condition if i select item name then only print regarding this data value like Rate, amount like this.

Example: online ordering food android app

Comment: if you tried something and ask for help it will be good in SO

Comment: it is not clear what you want so far.

Comment: i am developing online food ordering app, if i select item name then print this item  Rate , Gst  from json then calculate according to quantity

Comment: that depends on your existing code. You didn't show it.

Comment: if  I Increase Quantity then automatically add rate and Gst ,how can possible

Answer (score 0):

When you want to parse JSON , first you have to study about JSON Parsing.

You can Parse JSON by [Volley Library](https://www.androidhive.info/2014/09/android-json-parsing-using-volley/) ,  [Retrofit](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-retrofit-http-library/) etc.

Site to convert JSON to POJO/Model class [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

Steps to Parse JSON :

1. Create Pojo class according to your json.
2. Using Volley or Retrofit to parse the json.
3. After setting data on pojo send the ArrayList to Recyclerview Adapter class.

   You can also use GSON , its easy to parse json and set data to pojo classes.

   ```
     GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
               Gson mGson = builder.create();
               List<ItemObject> posts = new ArrayList<ItemObject>();
               posts = Arrays.asList(mGson.fromJson(response, ItemObject[].class));
               adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, posts);
               recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
   ```

Below is the tutorial to Json Parsing using Volley Library and set to RecyclerView .

Reference : https://inducesmile.com/android/android-json-parsing-using-gson-and-recyclerview/

> How can make condition if i select item name then only print regarding
>   this data value like Rate, amount like this.

Ans : By position you can get the values of rate, amount on that position data on Recyclerview Adapter class.

**How to pass all recyclerView data to next activity and save sqlite database in android, inside onclick Listener ?**

When you want to send recyclerView Data to next Activity, you have to send the pojo class object to next activity by intent.

**RecyclerView Data send to next Activity :**

```
  takeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

           //Data send to next Activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,TakeSingleScanActivity.class);
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putSerializable("ARRAYLIST",(Serializable)cList);
            intent.putExtra("BUNDLE",args);

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

**RecyclerView Data Receive from Last Activity :**

```
    ArrayList<LoadDataResult> inList; //Global Variable

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle args = intent.getBundleExtra("BUNDLE");
    inList = (ArrayList<LoadDataResult>) args.getSerializable("ARRAYLIST");
```

**Don't forget to implements your pojo class as Serializable :**

```
public class LoadDataResult implements Serializable{
```

**Create a loop to store all recyclerview data on Sqlite on your Activity Class :**

```
 for(int m = 0;m<mList.get(0).getResult().size();m++) {

                                        callDataBaseHelper(mList.get(0).getResult().get(m).getName().trim(),
                                                mList.get(0).getResult().get(m).getSku().trim(),
                                                mList.get(0).getResult().get(m).getUpc().trim(),
                                                mList.get(0).getResult().get(m).getPrice().trim(),
                                                mList.get(0).getResult().get(m).getDisplaySize().trim(),
                                                mList.get(0).getResult().get(m).getDisplaySizeYes(),
                                                mList.get(0).getResult().get(m).getStatus().trim());

                                        if(m == mList.get(0).getResult().size()-1) {
                                            setData();
                                            getRefreshTime();
                                            utils.showtoast("Data Load Successful");
                                            utils.hideDialog();
                                        }
                                     }
```

**call DataBaseHelper class addData method :**

```
 private void callDataBaseHelper(String name, String sku, String upc, String price, String displaySize, int displaySizeYes, String status) {
        boolean insertData = databaseHelper.addData(name,sku,upc,price,displaySize,displaySizeYes,status);

//        if(insertData){
//            Log.e("Inserted","Inserted  ");
//        }else{
//            Log.e("NotInserted","NotInserted  ");
//        }


    }
```

**Create DataBaseHelper Class :**

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String TAG = "DatabaseHelper";
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "GiftsDatabase.db";
SQLiteDatabase db;

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME,null,Constants.DATABASE_VERSION);
}



@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    try{
        String createTable = " CREATE TABLE "+ Constants.TABLE_NAME +"(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+Constants.NAME+" TEXT, "+Constants.SKU+" TEXT ,"+Constants.UPC+" TEXT,"+Constants.PRICE+" TEXT, "+Constants.DISPLAY_SIZE+" TEXT, "+Constants.DISPLAY_SIZE_YES+" INTEGER , "+Constants.STATUS+" TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(createTable);
        String createTableCount = " CREATE TABLE "+ Constants.TABLE_NAME_COUNT +"(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+Constants.SKU_COUNT+" TEXT ,"+Constants.QUANTITY_COUNT+" TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(createTableCount);

        Log.e(TAG,"Created Database");
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("EXCEPTION",""+e);
    }

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL(" DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+Constants.TABLE_NAME);
    db.execSQL(" DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+Constants.TABLE_NAME_COUNT);
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean addData(String name , String sku, String upc , String price, String displaySize, int displaySizeYes, String status){
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(Constants.NAME, name );
    contentValues.put(Constants.SKU, sku );
    contentValues.put(Constants.UPC, upc );
    contentValues.put(Constants.PRICE, price );
    contentValues.put(Constants.DISPLAY_SIZE, displaySize );
    contentValues.put(Constants.DISPLAY_SIZE_YES, displaySizeYes );
    contentValues.put(Constants.STATUS, status );

    long result = db.insert(Constants.TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
    Log.e(TAG,""+upc+"  Inserted");

    if(result == -1) {
        return false;
    }else{
      //  Log.e(TAG,"value inserted");
        return true;
    }

}
```

Store Checked RecyclerView data on ArrayList in RecyclerView Adapter Class

```
ArrayList<YourPojoClass> data = new ArrayList<YourPojoClass>();
```

inside `onBindViewHolder();` This is used for store data in checked rows.

```
holder.checkBox..setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          data.add(name.get(position).getText,address.get(position).getText)       

      }
    });
```

**Send data to next Activity :** Create a button at bottom of the recyclerView by Your Activity , and you click on that button send data to next activity.

Comment: how to pass all recyclerView data to next activity and save sqlite database in android, inside onclick Listener ?

Comment: One think ask Boss ? How can insert  check box every RecyclerView data , if i select three item then send next activity and save in android .

Comment: One think ask Boss ? How can insert  check box every RecyclerView data , if i select three item then send next activity and save in android .

Comment: Add checkBox in every RecyclerView row and set listner on checkBox when you checked on checkBox get the position and store the data in new ArrayList of same Pojo class and send that new ArrayList to next activity.

Comment: How are you going to next Activity by Clicking any Button or any else ? @Rahul

Comment: If i click recyclerView data then go next screen boss

Comment: I have one question , If there are 10 rows in your recyclerview and every row containing a checkBox , you checked first 5 rows and how will  you go to the next Activity ?

Comment: My question is after checking first five rows , How will you are going to the next Activity ??

Comment: I want same implementation but i can not do please suggest how can do that.

Comment: if press a button like this how can add all things and place please btnSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
             

      }
    });

Comment: Just Understand what i am going to say........ suppose you have 10 rows you are getting all 10 rows by any pojo/model class , here you will create a same type of new  model/pojo class and when you checked on row get that row data and add to new pojo/model class and finally send that new pojo/model class to next Activity.

Comment: Every time get same value if pass intent and putExtra in side  onClick() please help?

Comment: Please Update your question with your code , without code its not possible to check @Rahul

Comment: public void clickItem1(View view){
        
        Intent intent = new Intent(MenuActivity.this,AddToCartActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        songTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.song_title);
        String s = songTitle.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra("name", s);
        startActivity(intent);}       SECOND ACTIVITY    Intent iin= getIntent();
        Bundle b = iin.getExtras();

        if(b!=null)
        {
            String j =(String) b.get("name");
            textView.setText(j);
        }

Comment: And how you are getting data post that too @Rahul , if you will update you question with your Activity code then it will be better for me identify bugs.

Comment: if pass value one activity to another activity though Intent then every time get same value ?

Comment: if pass value one activity to another activity though Intent then every time get same value ?

Comment: Are you getting the value on next activity ?  When you get the value in your next Activity just clear the ArrayList Data when you press back.

Comment: edit your question by clicking on edit at below of the question and update you code @Rahul